# Service mast install - is this okay?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Okay, the electrician came out and did my panel upgrade. I am asking opinions about the service mast set-up as it looks a little different than usual. The mast is above a patio deck, so he really tightened up the lines to keep them high. I really didn't think of any of the following until after he left.

In the 1st pic, you can see the drip loop does not droop down as far as I'm used to seeing. It looks serviceable, but I'm not sure. In pic 2, there is a bit of exposed copper in what I am assuming is the neutral. I guess this is okay, but I am just asking. Lastly, the 3rd pic, you can see how tight the line is to the telephone pole. It seems most lines have a bit of sag in them.

Is this something I need to worry about? Should anything be redone?
[image]

Comment: That lug there is aluminum, and so are the lugs on the meter, so what was the goal of using copper wire there?  Anyway, that splice is owned by the power company, not you, and is their problem. Can't touch that!

Comment: Now I have an ear worm.

Comment: Did the power ompany make up that weatherhead or your electrician.  It really looks sloppy.  Is that power pole leaning?  The tension looks tight for a service drop.

Comment: No, the pole isn't leaning. It's just the way the photo turned out as I was trying to get it all into one picture.

Answer (score 2):

That splice there belongs to the *power company*.  It is their bailwick, it's on them if it fails.

I assume the power company installed it when your electrician called them to come out and re-connect your house after the work was done. Those lines are always energized and have no circuit breaker protection, so they need to be moved by the power company.  The electrician would have no way to turn them off unless they have a special relationship with the power company (e.g. are a former lineman) to shimmy up their pole and mess with the utility wires on their behalf.

So if that splice fails, that would be a practical problem for you, because you'd have a "Lost Neutral" and wonky voltages as a result (including 120V lines going higher than 120V).  But it's the power company's *responsibility*, so they'd need to buy you new appliances.  Unless you mess with it, in which case all bets are off.

Now if that wire there is copper because you insisted against your electrician's advice, I'd suggest not insisting in the future. When wires get this large, copper gives no advantage and some disadvantage.  That lug connector in your photo? The body is *made of aluminum*. So are almost all large lugs.

Comment: No, the power company did not come out. The electrician crew showed up and did it themselves. The power to  the house was shut off for a few hours but that was it.  I did not insist on anything, I let the electricians do their jobs assuming they knew what they were doing. This still hasn't been inspected for the permit. This should be next week.

Answer (score 1):

So the electrician did all the connections and sagged the service drop. In many areas, the electrician is not allowed to make those connections. The power company shuts off the power, the electricians do the work and the power company waits for the inspection, then makes the connections before turning the power back on. In some areas, the electrician can make those connections so the power comes on quickly but the inspection follows and then the power company comes out and replaces those connections with their own.

If it passes inspection, you should call the power company and tell them your concerned about the work. They will probably come out and replace the service drop because it's too short and then redo all the connections with the proper connectors. Check with the inspector, they might, by procedure, make the call to the power company to have the connections redone.

Comment: Still wondering if the exposed copper is a problem in inself. Like it will get wet when it rains. I am guessing not as the aluminum is bare, but I don't know. This is the first time I've ever been forced to question a service mast connection.

Comment: @Kim  The exposed copper neutral is not a problem.  I'm not sure about that connector though.  It needs to be torqued to specifications and I doubt the electrician did that. I've never seen one used like that.  Wai for the inspector and then call the power company.   I'm surprised you even notied the mast, most people don't pay attention.